# Cutting this simple graph; is my reasoning right?

Tags: graph-theory

I have read about a simple graph not being able to have a `cut vertex` with the *valency* of one. Interesting, because I think it's possible, but probably my reasoning is wrong. Could you correct me, please?

I was thinking about this simple graph:

```
O ------ 0
a        b
```

So, as you can see, I have a simple graph with two vertices, A and B. When I'd remove A, for example, I'd have vertex B left.... does the definition of a vertex cut mean that I'd be removing A and it's edge, which means we have just one vertex (B) left?

It's not *disconnected* anymore... as there is just one *component*. And yes, while I am writing this, I am actually proving myself wrong and stating that it's indeed not possible to have a cut vertex with a valency of one, yet I'd like to be roasted and need a confirmation of my own reasoning.

Comment: The self-learning tag is not to be used just because you are studying on your own, it is meant to be used about the *process* of learning on your own and for questions about pedagogy... not about the material itself that you are studying.  As to the content of your question, a cut vertex will never have degree one because its deletion would never increase the number of components, and you can prove this.  "*Its not disconnected anymore*"... it was never disconnected in the first place, so I'm not sure where you are going with that...

Comment: True! I wanted to state: "it's not disconnected, because there is just one component left" and for something to be a cut vertex, it needs more than 1 component. Thanks for the heads up and confirmation!

Comment: As for a proof of the fact, recommend using the definition of connected that says $G$ is connected if for every pair of vertices $u,v$ one can find a path between $u$ and $v$.  The graph $G\setminus\{x\}$ where $x$ is a vertex of degree one will have the same path between $u$ and $v$ as it did before so long as neither of $u$ nor $v$ are the deleted vertex $x$ since otherwise that would imply that $x$ fell along the path somewhere, but as such a path would have to enter $x$ from one edge and leave $x$ from another that would contradict the hypothesis that $x$ was degree one